# Web Forms For Marketers Form Designer throws 'Handle Not Found' Error

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

In Sitecore 7.2, opening FormDesigner gives the following error:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Handle not found.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Web.UrlHandle.Get(UrlString urlString, String handleName, Boolean removeSessionValue)
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.Utility.Utils.GetDataSource(String url) in C:\Users\Raymond.Weng\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\v01\DecompilerCache\decompiler\DA67A299-0E6A-4A9B-A8E1-031DAB1327EB\e6\7823a5d7\Utils.cs:line 219
   at Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDesigner.GetCurrentItem() in C:\Users\Raymond.Weng\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\v01\DecompilerCache\decompiler\DA67A299-0E6A-4A9B-A8E1-031DAB1327EB\a8\50ab1903\FormDesigner.cs:line 723
   at Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDesigner.LoadControls() in C:\Users\Raymond.Weng\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\v01\DecompilerCache\decompiler\DA67A299-0E6A-4A9B-A8E1-031DAB1327EB\a8\50ab1903\FormDesigner.cs:line 163
   at Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDesigner.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Raymond.Weng\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\v01\DecompilerCache\decompiler\DA67A299-0E6A-4A9B-A8E1-031DAB1327EB\a8\50ab1903\FormDesigner.cs:line 128

Request information: 
Request URL: http://myurl/sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form Designer?xmlcontrol=Forms.FormDesigner 
Request path: /sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form Designer 
User host address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
User: sitecore\admin 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

I think something is wrong with the installation, but comparing the instance with the WFFM install files, I cant see whats missing. Not even sure what Handle Not Found means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ultimately came down to the URL. Sitecore was set to inject the language into the URL automatically (This is a setting in the linkManager section of the web config). WFFM really didnt like this. When I changed that setting, everything was fine.

**UPDATE**

An example patch would be:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <linkManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="sitecore">
                <patch:attribute name="languageEmbedding">never</patch:attribute>                   
            </add>
        </providers>
    </linkManager>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding forms from the experience editor? If so are you able to actually add a form to a page? Are there any console errors when you do this?

Could you check for console errors?
Have you re-installed web forms for marketeers in Sitecore?

Charlie :)

Comment: I get a couple of 'deprecated' warnings, but the error is 'Failed to load resource' and the resource is '/sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form Designer'. Going to try re-installing

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.